# Windows server VM can't access internet through pfSense

Tags: windows-server-2016, virtualbox, pfsense

System overview:
1.Ubuntu 18.4 running virtualbox.
2.Two VM machines, pfSense firewall and windows server 2016.

I'am trying to configure the windows server to go through the pfSense, so i chosed a internal network from Virtualbox initial setup.
The windows server take it's ip through DHCP normally, and am able to access the pfSense from the windows server web browser.
But, Ican't go the internet.
The windows server dosn't see the WAN interface of pfSense and Vice versa.
Please help and suport.
Any suggestions

Comment: Does the other VM have connectivity?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Vm's have connectivity between each others.
I did a 1:1 Nat in firewall, and I disabled the bridge connection and enabled it again